# Cycles baking testbuild gives black image (no displacement used)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I've been using Blender for a few months to make the models for a game (actual game engine is Unity Free). I'm new to Blender and 3D modelling in general, so please be patient with me if I'm doing something stupid or I use the wrong terminology.

Anyways, I got the Blender 2.71 testbuild 2 and I've been using it for baking in my Cycles materials for my game. It's been working pretty good, but for one of my models it isn't working. I go and press "Bake" with bake type set to "Combined" and I wait there for an hour or so and instead of baking the model in full color (like it normally does), the UV's are all black (see "combined bake.png"). Am I doing something wrong here? (I've uploaded my .blend file if anyone wants to see it.)

Also, this is how I normally do cycles baking (this has worked for my other models): First, I go into edit mode and do a Smart UV project. Then I go into one of my materials and open up the node editor. I add a Texture Coordinate node. Then I add an Image Texture node and set the file to whichever file I want to bake to. I then take the UV from the Texture Coordinate and put it into the Vector node in the Image Texture. I repeat the process for each of the object's materials. Then I go to Render>Bake and press Bake with the type set to combined bake. This normally does work for my other models. The only thing different with this one is that there is a crystal thing hovering over the object I'm baking. The crystal has a strong emission shader. Is there anything wrong here?

I'm using 1000 samples if anyone wants to know.

(Note: I tried this on the Blender 2.71 RC1 from http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/graphics/ble...e/Blender2.71/ that just came out - still no luck.)

**rendered.png**:
[image: Rendered image using 1000 samples.]

**combined bake.png**
[image]

[**full file.blend** This my blend file that I'm using for this model.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rt7215trlsx3c82/full%20file.blend)

Comment: Here is the same question on blenderartists.org: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?340049-Cycles-baking-testbuild-gives-black-image-%28no-displacement-used%29. Sorry for cross-posting, it's just that I'm afraid my question isn't getting much attention there.

Comment: Did you try recalculating the normals (Ctrl-N in Edit Mode)? That sometimes fixes it.

Comment: @CharlesL Thank you! Now the combined bake is working properly. I felt like was missing something simple.

Comment: @CharlesL Feel free to add that as an answer :)

Comment: @gandalf3 done :D

Comment: Try switching from GPU to CPU rendering. I've had a similar problem, and that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to recalculate the normals of the object (*Edit Mode* > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>).

If you don't, the normals will all face inward (where there is no light).